# problems adding views to vGroup

Tags: java, android

I want to add some Views to a ViewGroup in my Android project but i am getting wired problems.

First of all, i have a ListView and an EditText which are in a Linearlayout.

I am creating these this way:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
linearLayout.setId(1001);

EditText eText = new EditText(getActivity());
eText.setHint("Suche");
eText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayout.addView(eText);
```

in function `onCreateView`, so i just return linearLayout.

Later, in another function i want to add the ListView:

```
modeList.setAdapter(adapter);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) vGroup.findViewById(1001);
layout.addView(modeList);
```

But it only shows the EditText Box. If i dont add the EditText it shows the ListView, but in a bad behavior:

Left: ListView, Right: with EditText
[image: app Layout]

So my problem is: First, why is the ListView not in full width? And second, why there is no ListView if i add the EditText?

ListItem xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:text="TEST"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPosition"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom|left"
            android:text="drittens"
            android:textColor="#0000ff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtVideos"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="nochmal"
        android:textColor="#00ff00"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you doing so much layout work in code?

Comment: Because it is in a ViewGroup for a ViewPager. Your answer was alomst right. I added the line `linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);` and now it works. Both problems solved with one line. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> android:orientation="horizontal"

change to

> android:orientation="vertical"

Comment: That was the Problem. Thanks !